# Unable to unmarshal AWS SQS message in GO

Tags: go, amazon-sqs

Folks,

Am trying to unmarshal a message from an SQS FIFO queue, and am getting

```
cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field SendMessageInput.MessageAttributes of type map[string]*sqs.MessageAttributeValue
```

```
// unmarshal for the sqs message
var publishedMessage sqs.SendMessageInput
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*msg.Body), &publishedMessage); err != nil {
  onError(err)
  continue
}

// unmarhsal for the message sent
var result Message
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*publishedMessage.MessageBody), &result); err != nil {
    onError(err)
    continue
}
```

The Message itself looks ok when i look at the message via the SQS console.

Here is a sample messageAttributes section from the message:

```
"messageAttributes":[{"name":"foo","dataType":"String","attributeValue":"something"},{"name":"uid","dataType":"String","attributeValue":"26799e9c-9455-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64"}]
```

From the SDK documentation:

```
// Each message attribute consists of a Name, Type, and Value. For more information,
    // see Amazon SQS Message Attributes (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html)
    // in the Amazon Simple Queue Service Developer Guide.
    MessageAttributes map[string]*MessageAttributeValue `locationName:"MessageAttribute" locationNameKey:"Name" locationNameValue:"Value" type:"map" flattened:"true"`
```

What am I doing wrong here folks?

Comment: If their SDK defines the field as a map, but their API returns a json array for that value then the problem seems to be with their SDK, or API, since they are at odds with each other.

Comment: ... if that's the case, then you can work around this by first unmarshaling into a custom type, one that matches the json, and then if you need to you can convert that to the SDK type manually.

Comment: 100%.  Problem resolved.  I definitely can not trust their SDK...  unmarshaling to sqs.Message type worked.

Answer (score 6):

For those who stumble upon this...

```
// Message encapsulates all the information to publish in a message
type Message struct {
    Body              json.RawMessage            `json:"body"`
    Headers           map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"headers"`
    Environment       string                     `json:"env"`
    PublishTime       int64                      `json:"publishTime"`
    MessageAttributes []Attributes               `json:"messageAttributes"`
}

for _, msg := range resp.Messages {

  var result Message
  if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*msg.Body), &result); err != nil {
    onError(err)
    continue
  }

  metadata := &Metadata{
    ReceiptHandle: *msg.ReceiptHandle,
    MD5OfBody:     *msg.MD5OfBody,
    SQSMessageID:  *msg.MessageId,
    ReceiveCount:  *msg.Attributes[sqs.MessageSystemAttributeNameApproximateReceiveCount],
  }

  onMessage(result, *metadata)

}
```

Comment: Hi @Cmag, can you please show the code for parsing the *sqs.Message into Go lang struct. I have been trying to parse it.